# Why is my multiplication operation returning zero?

Tags: c, unix

I wrote my first program in c just to practice. However, I don't know why it doesn't work ? The result of `socks * price;` in the code snippet below is zero. What am I missing here ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
      int socks;
      float price, total;

      printf("How many socks >> ");
      scanf(" %d", &socks);

      printf("What is the price for each pair ?");
      scanf(" %.3f", &price);

      total = socks * price;
      printf("\n\nTotal: %.3f", total);

return 0;
}
```

It is a normal multiplication; I first wanted to know how many `socks` did the user pay let's say `4`, and the `price` for the single pair, let's say `100.000` per `sock` ( that's a lot for socks, I know, but this is just for example).

`Total` is a `float` number, therefore `4 * 100.000 =` should give the `total` price = `400.000` but I am getting `0`.

Comment: use "%f" only for price - if you printf your price you see the problem. Then, `int main(void)` is more correct than what you wrote.

Comment: Had you enabled/paid attention to compiler warnings, would you have found that `scanf("%.3f")` is incorrect. (TBH, I didn't notice it either, `clang` told me so.) And anyway, don't use `scanf()`. **At all.** Use sane I/O and conversion functions such as `fgets()` and `strtod()`.

Comment: (try also `int x = scanf(" %.3f", &price);` then print x, you will see 0: it means no part of the string were recognized as "%.3f"; the price is left at its value, and since you have not initialized it....)

Comment: @H2CO3: I don't entirely agree with your last point. `scanf` is simpler for something like this; the problem is that has very poor error handling. It's probably easier to learn to use `scanf` (and ignore what it does on incorrect input) *and then* learn `fgets` and `strtod` than to try to learn `fgets` and `strtod` from scratch.

Comment: @KeithThompson I see where you're coming from, although I don't think that learning one function would be particularly more difficult than learning another. (In this case, anyway.)

Comment: @H2CO3 in fact, never said that. He gets 0 by chance. I get -0.00014, by the way, in a run.

Comment: @H2CO3 x in `x = scanf...`

Comment: @ShinTakezou Aham. Yup. I think I should just go to sleep. (My eyes are sharpened for "uninitialized variable will be 0" assertions, because unfortunately, a lot of people write that... forgive my premature reaction!)

Comment: .... maybe I should complete the sentence to make it clearer: and since you have not inizialized it (the price var).... you get `socks * whatever`, `whatever` being... whatever (0, almost 0, 101912.333... whatever)

Comment: Lol ! I'm just a newbie, so not big deal :P all these details won't be necessary.

Comment: Programming needs very sharp eye. Every mistake counts and it makes a huge impact over the program's functionality; that's what I noticed in the very early days of my programming journey, but you guys are my sharp eye.

Comment: Minor note:  The space in `" %d"` and `" %f"` is not needed.  Both `%d %f` consume leading whitespace without it.  Its presences is OK though.

Comment: My question sounds fairly trivial!, but anyway I was trying to figure out what's the problem, it always must be something and asking a silly question is not always silly. Every innovation starts from the silliness.'Apology'

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is an incorrect usage of scanf. We don't use the formating "%.3f" with scanf. Instead you can use it when printing the output

```
      printf("What is the price for each pair ?");
      scanf("%f", &price);

      total = socks * price;
      printf("\n\nTotal: %.3f", total);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved the problem :) and thanks for everyone who helped me... especially ShinTakezou for provding more details about why we can't use %.3f in scanf() function.*****

Answer (score 1):

change as follows

```
scanf(" %f", &price);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the format to `scanf(" %.3f", &price);` was invalid, the *larger problem* is in not using the `scanf()` return value

```
if (scanf("%f", &price) != 1) {
  handle_bad_put();
}
```

Without testing the result of `scanf()`, one does not know if `price` was set.  Not using the correct format could still fool a `scanf()` result, but with `scanf()` tendency for problems, testing its results  is defensive coding and should be considered obligatory.

Answer (score 0):

your main function is returning an int so therefore

```
int main() 
{
   ...
}
```

And when you get the input for price it should be

```
scanf("%f", &price);
```

Comment: in C, you don't need to specify the `int main`, just `main` works too

Comment: They're many people out there who argue about int main() I just type it main() and it works pretty well, it could be in C++ not in C I guess...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the format for scanf, as in scanf, it should be the following:
     %[*][width][length]specifier
So you cannot use a precision field like in printf.

The resource for your reference:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/